# Best way to record player's orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the best way to keep record of the player's orientation in driving game where the player races around a track in a car? ( matrix, euler angles or quaternions)!

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions are usually the best way to go, since that's how Unity's APIs treat rotations. Store/use quaternions, convert to other formats when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a class for the Player then that class will have a Transform which will always know the position and rotation of your player.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
     void printPlayerOrientation()
     {
         Debug.Log(transform.rotation);
     }
}
```

`transform.rotation` is a Quaternion by the way.